# Ошибка в консоли после создания нового проекта на React

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

Столкнулся с проблемой после создания проекта(npx create-react-app) запустил его(npm start) но после запуска выдаёт ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

    at Object.injectIntoGlobalHook (react-refresh-runtime.development.js:465)
    
    at Object../node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/client/ReactRefreshEntry.js 

    (ReactRefreshEntry.js:8)
    
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856)
    
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    
    at Object.1 (reportWebVitals.js:14)
    
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:856)
    
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    
    at main.chunk.js:1
```

гуглил но не нашёл ничего

Comment: Вы не изменяли проект?

Comment: Попробуйте переустановить

Comment: @Voprositel проект не коим образом не изменял, как только вышла последняя версия реакта появилась эта ошибка, уже три раза переустанавливал ни какого эффекта

Comment: Значит, проблема в самом реакт, попробуйте откатиться.